# no site master page found in mvc 4 web application visual studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

i have visual studio 2013 with mvc 4. I have created all types of mvc web applications but still can't find any site.master in shared folder of VIEW as there exist cshtml files.

I have found on google that site.master can be accessed in mvc 2 visual studio 2010. can I have access here instead of cshtml files?

Comment: instead of site.master there is _layout.cshtml file that can be used in mvc 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Site.Master is designed for ASP.NET WebForms and it is no longer a standard in ASP.NET MVC.

The alternative for a "site.master" is the default file "_Layout.cshtml" which is found in "Views\Shared".

As for using .master (which means you want to use ASP Controls instead of RAZOR engine) then I'd recommend not to use MVC at all since that will simply mess up your overall code and with no benefits.